# function returns all the same random number

Tags: c++, random

I have a function in c++, which returns a random float number between two numbers. Here is the code:

```
float randFloatNumBetween(float lower, float upper) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    return lower + ((float) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (upper - lower); 
}
```

When I call this function with parameters where lower is 0.0 and upper 10.0, it returns numbers like:

```
1.00503555
1.01846383
1.03463534
1.05263234
1.06461514
```

How can I make my function returns different numbers before and after the comma? Numbers like:

```
5.00503555
3.01846383
1.03463534
4.05263234
8.06461514
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you need to change the seed value each time you call `srand`. Based on the comments you've left this doesn't appear to be your problem, but it needs to be pointed out.

Some random number generators (I know Microsoft's `rand` to be one) have a correlation between the initial seed and the first number generated. Since the time doesn't change very fast, the numbers you get from seeding with it tend to be correlated as well.

The best way around this is to use a better random number generator such as the C++11 ones in the `<random>` header: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random or their predecessors in the boost library.

Otherwise just make sure you generate a couple of throw-away random numbers after you seed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `srand` in each iteration but [`srand` should be called only once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21726414/2455888). Place `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` outside of this function, in the file scope.

Comment: But now I dont understand this, why does it everytime i call the program still return the same number in current time? Shouldn't it also change the first 2 digits when I run for a second time program?

Comment: No. It will not. Read the accepted answer in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C++11 features you can do the following:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type randNumBetween(T lower, T upper, std::default_random_engine &gnr) {
  if(lower > upper) std::swap(lower, upper);
  std::uniform_real_distribution<T> distribution(lower, upper);
  return distribution(gnr);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type randNumBetween(T lower, T upper, std::default_random_engine &gnr) {
  if(lower > upper) std::swap(lower, upper);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(lower, upper);
  return distribution(gnr);
}

int main() {
  auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine gnr(seed);
  for(auto i(0); i < 10; ++i) std::cout << randNumBetween(10, 20, gnr) << std::endl;
  for(auto i(0); i < 10; ++i) std::cout << randNumBetween(10.0, 20.0, gnr) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55b66f688c8b686e)

In this nice [video lecture](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) Stephan T. Lavavej explains why use of `rand()` is considered harmful and unsafe.